# Difference between IOS viewmodel and Android viewmodel

Tags: android, ios, mvvm, android-viewmodel

We have both android and ios apps and trying to make it similar almost with architecture. IOS is ahead of us for now, and they create viewmodel almost for everything. For example, we have list of posts. They have viewmodel that hold that list. Then they have viewmodel for one post. Then viewmodel for post comment, viewmodel for reaction etc. In Android world it seems general idea is one viewmodel per screen but with this I will finish with at least 5 viewmodels in one screen. Is there in general difference between IOS viewmodel and Android viewmodel and how they work?!

Comment: Simple answer -> Don't do that .. Do not try to make it similar .. Both platform are different and have their own sets of best practices for code architecture So you should stick to this only .. Now having a `viewmodel` for each resource is not very feasible IMO .. It should be for one screen minimum or depending on the requirement and complexity of Data  you can divide it further ..

Comment: ok thx a lot. so you would not for every part of post that can potentially change create view model?

Comment: There is no difference between iOS/Android in this example - it is not a common practice on both platforms. If your list is lazy and "infinite", this can lead to creating a lot of objects - but you can come up with a mechanism to reuse your models. I'd say it's usually redundant, but it shouldn't be a problem if done carefully.